# Haskell ghci read behaviour with * and max

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

So I've just encountered the following in ghci:

```
    (*) (read "10") (read "20")
```

returns 200 as expected. However, this line

```
    (max) (read "10") (read "20")
```

throws an exception:

```
    *** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

And I can't really figure out the cause for such ghci behaviour. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an instance of GHCi’s defaulting rules. When it encounters an ambiguous type, it selects `()` (“unit”) as the default. So it’s attempting to read `10` as a value of type `()`, which fails to parse.

The type is ambiguous because `read`’s return type is overloaded to work on any instance of `Read`, and `max`’s parameter type is overloaded to work on any instance of `Ord`, so the compiler doesn’t have any way to know which type you intended for the intermediate values:

```
read :: (Read a) => String -> a
max :: (Ord a) => a -> a -> a
```

You will also see this behaviour if you simply write this:

```
read "10"
```

But writing this will work:

```
read "()"
```

One solution is to give an explicit type annotation:

```
max (read "10" :: Int) (read "20" :: Int)
```

This returns `20` as expected.

You can also disable this behaviour with a command-line flag:

```
ghci -XNoExtendedDefaultRules
```

Or with a GHCi command:

```
:set -XNoExtendedDefaultRules
```

And then you will get an appropriate error message along the lines of “No instance for `Ord a0`…the type variable `a0` is ambiguous”.

Comment: Indeed, one `:: Int` is enough.

Comment: @addy2012: True, though in this case I prefer to be explicit and avoid relying on inference. For example, I generally prefer to write `[a, b, c] :: [Int]` rather than `[a :: Int, b, c]` even though it’s slightly redundant.